# Form in Access modifying my Comments when they're put into a Table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

Created Form in Access 2016 but when it it writes out my Comments for each Record in a Table, it's beginning them with

`"<DIV>"`

and ending the comment with

**`"</DIV>"`**.

How can I get rid of these 'adjustments' to just include my written record/comment? Also when I use an 
&
in a sentence, it's writing it as
`"&amp;"`... 
So I always have to go back to the Table and amend my Comments, before running a Report. YOUR HELP WOULD BE SO GREATLY APPRECIATED!

Comment: Are field and textbox set as Rich Text?

Comment: Yes they were.  Just changed to Plain Text and my problem is solved!  Thank you so much :)